# Spring HibernateTemplate - is contain / find / get value by class name & non-ID-param

Tags: hibernate, spring

For refrence look http://singgihpraditya.wordpress.com/2010/02/13/spring-3-0-and-hibernate-tutorial-part-1/

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements Serializable {
        private Long id;
    private String name;
private String password;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="USER_ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }
```

the above part is code from 2 files , just to give you some code as people here like to ask for it

the important part:

```
@Override
public User getUser(Long id) {
    return hibernateTemplate.get(User.class, id);

}
```

As we can see get User by his ID is easy..
I want to  :  i'm sure its easy I just dont know how , and I know there is the alternative way to get all User into a a `List<User>` and serach with `for(..)` but I don't want that way, I want the elegant way.

* return user by name

* return true/false if user exists by name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need queries to search for entities. Read the [user guide about queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying). The same page also contains a whole section about HQL, the query language used to write queries.

Comment: thx worked , ppl I wanted a sulution with hibernateTemplate if u didn't undetstand...
`return  hibernateTemplate.find("from User where name =" + "'" + userName + "'").isEmpty();` but its the same so nm ^^

Comment: @Zakos: HibernateTemplate is just a thin wrapper around Hibernate. Its central method (as noted inits javadoc) is execute, which gives you access to the Hibernate session through the callback argument, that you must implement. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#execute%28org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateCallback%29

Answer (score 1):

It's something like this, more and less:

```
String sqlQuery =" from User
 as user where user.name=:name";

Query query = session.createQuery
(SQL_QUERY);

query.setString("name",name);

List<User>  = query.list();
```

For more information see this chapter

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql

Comment: You should respect the Java naming conventions : sqlQuery instead os SQL_QUERY. Moreover, it's not a SQL query, but a HQL query. It's setString(), not addString(). And it's user.name = :name, not user.name:=name. Finally, I would point the OP to a more recent version of the doc. 3.6 is the latest stable release.

Comment: @JB Nizet, you are absolutely right :) I gave you point on your answer for that. I wrote it without seeing my code as i remembered

Comment: thx , but u missundetstood the point , I wanted solution with the use of `hibernateTemplate` which `hibernatTempoalte.get(queryString)` also fines :)